# How to publish a post on Facebook Page using CURL and without using SDK in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am developing a PHP project that needs Facebook integration. So before I do it on code , I am testing it using Facebook Graph API explorer tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). What I am doing now is.

> 1st Step

```
Get the user access_token by using the button at the top left.
```

> 2nd Step

```
Make a GET request to "me/accounts" to get the page token and page id.
```

> 3rd Step

```
Make a POST request to "{page_id}/feed" with the fields message={message} and access_token={page_token}
```

It worked perfectly and posted on my Facebook Fan Page. But when I try to replace the "3rd Step" with PHP code like this

```
$data['message'] = "my message";


$data['access_token'] = $page_access_token; //page token from 2nd step
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


$resp = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$data_resp = json_decode($resp);

print_r($data_resp);
```

It show me this error.

```
stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [message] => (#200) Permissions error [type] => OAuthException [code] => 200 ) )
```

> I set the permissions of manage_pages,publish_pages,publish_actions

Comment: debug your `access_token` and check if it is getting the required permissions. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 2):

Passing an array for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` means cURL will send the request as Content-Type `multipart/form-data` – but you want `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead.

Use `http_build_query` on your `$data` array, and use the resulting string for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#publish

> **Permissions**
>
> - A user access token with `publish_actions` permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that person. Posts will appear in the voice of the user.
> - A page access token with `publish_pages` permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that page. Posts will appear in the voice of the page.

You should run the used access token through

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

to see whether it contains the appropriate permission(s).

Comment: Yes . The token is fine and it includes all the permissions required .